# How to use autowired servises in conversation services

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I wish to understand  how right to use `autowired` in  converter class.

I have SomeConverter class which implement GenericConverter.
Converter was registered by `ConversionServiceFactoryBean`.

```
   @Component
  public class ReportConverter implements GenericConverter {

@Autowired
private UsrService usrService; //null

@Override
public final Set<ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes() {
    Set<ConvertiblePair> types = new HashSet<>();
    types.add(new ConvertiblePair(ReportDTO.class, Document.class));
    types.add(new ConvertiblePair(Document.class, ReportDTO.class));
    return types;
}

@Override
public final Object convert(Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
///
return dto;
}
```

When i try use `@autowired` annatation or implemets `ApplicationContextAware` interface in Converter class i get null reference.
 Separately UsrServese and Converter work is fine.

```
 @Slf4j
  @Service
  public class UsrServiceImpl implements UsrService {

 @Bean(name = "conversionService")
public ConversionService getConversionService(ApplicationContext context) {
Map<String, ReportConverter> reportConverter = context.getBeansOfType(ReportConverter.class);
    HashSet<GenericConverter> converters = new HashSet<>();
    ...
   converters.addAll(reportConverter.values());

    ConversionServiceFactoryBean bean = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean() {
        @Override
        public void afterPropertiesSet() {
            super.afterPropertiesSet();
            dpdContextConverter.values().forEach(cv -> cv.setConversionService(getObject()));
        }
    };
    bean.setConverters(converters);
    bean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return bean.getObject();
}
```

Comment: How did you annotate `UsrService`?

Comment: UserServiceImp  annataded as @Service

Comment: Can you show me how `ConversionServiceFactoryBean` comes into play?

Comment: Added part of the code.

Comment: Sorry, the formatting looks weird. Could you try to fix it? Is method `getConversionService` part of `UsrService`?

Comment: Looks like you have a cyclic dependency: `UsrServiceImpl` uses `ReportConverter` and `ReportConverter` uses `UsrServiceImpl`.

Comment: Can you extract the method `getConversionService` to a class annotated with `@Configuration`?

Comment: The class in which this method resides is @Configuration. Moreover, this method is in the start class of the application in the same place as the main method.

Thank you for your help and responsiveness, but it will probably be correct if I study the documentation more deeply.

Comment: It is hard to solve it by the snippets. One more advice: try to use constructor injection instead of field injection. Good luck!

Comment: You can try to replace field injection by constructor injection. It is likely that using field exception the `ReportConverter` beans that you fetch from application context are not fully constructed due to field injection.